# JSON.parse wouldn't parse a JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

```
a = "{key:'14',data:{order: '154'}}"

JSON.parse(a)
```

expected behavior:

```
{key:'14',data:{order: '154'}}
```

result:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: It isn't valid JSON (though it would be valid JavaScript). The keys need to be double quoted, and the values also double-quoted, not single. Validate it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @michael  if the value is number , it can be without quotes

Comment: @loneshark99 But in no case are single quotes valid..

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON is not valid.

You should try:

```
a = '{"key":"14","data":{"order": "154"}}'

JSON.parse(a)
```

Valid JSON requires both property and values to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: beat me to it!  google for an online validator like this one:  http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate and it may help.

Comment: Properties and *string* values. `null`, `true`, `false` and numerics should not be quoted (unless you want a string with those contents).

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Json , Json keys are always in quotes for it to be valid .

Answer (score 0):

It is not JSON. Your hash is stored as `string` not `JSON`. so you need **[eval](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval)** for expected output:

```
> a = "{key:'14',data:{order: '154'}}"
> eval(a)
#=> {:key=>"14", :data=>{:order=>"154"}}
```

---

Let me convert your hash to json and show you how it looks and how you can parse JSON.

```
# sample of your hash
> hash = {key:'14',data:{order: '154'}} 

# convert hash to json and assign it to a
> a = hash.to_json 
#=> "{\"key\":\"14\",\"data\":{\"order\":\"154\"}}" 

# parse correct JSON format
> JSON.parse(a) 
#=> {"key"=>"14", "data"=>{"order"=>"154"}}
```